# Encountered "=" error in Jmeter when List is used in jmeter beanshell code

Tags: java, list, collections, jmeter

Below is my code.

```
package findDuplicatre;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindDuplicate {


     public static void main(String[] args) {
         String[] ContentNameCount = {"name1","name1","name2","name2", "name2"};
        List<String> sampleList = (List<String>) Arrays.asList(ContentNameCount);
         for(String inpt:ContentNameCount){
         int frequency=Collections.frequency(sampleList,inpt);
         log.error(inpt+" "+frequency); //System.out.println(inpt+" "+frequency);
         }
     }
```

}

In eclipse i could get results:

```
    name1 2
    name1 2
    name2 3
    name2 3
    name2 3
```

When i could run the same code in Eclipse without any error.But when i run the same code in jmeter beanshell sampler i'm getting below errors.

```
Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  In file: inline evaluation of: ``package findDuplicatre;  import java.util.*; import java.util.Collections; impor . . . '' Encountered "=" at line 13, column 41.
```

Can anyone kindly explain me what am i missing and how would it make difference when i run in beanshell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beanshell is not Java, you need to stick to [Java SE 1.5](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/relnotes-139183.html) language features in general. In particular your case you need to remove [diamond operators](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java/jdk-7--the-diamond-operator.html) from your code as they were introduced in Java 7 and Beanshell doesn't support them like:

```
List sampleList = Arrays.asList(ContentNameCount);
```

---

A better option would be going for [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language. Groovy is compatible with all modern Java language features, moreover it has much better performance comparing to Beanshell. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for more details.

Comment: Hi Dmitri T. Thankyou.Its working now. And yes i'll try  JSR223 element .

Answer (score 0):

@Dmitri T answer is valid, you can still overcome the exception (remove diamond operators) in Beanshell:

```
String[] sampleList = {"name1","name1","name2","name2", "name2"};
for(String inpt:sampleList){
     int frequency=Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(sampleList),inpt);
     log.error(inpt+" "+frequency); //System.out.println(inpt+" "+frequency);
}
```